# Make sure that the Git push is from the same tree

Tags: git

I have a central git repo in which I deleted its old history, causing all the sha IDs to be changed. So I have a new first commit. I want to prevent people from pushing the old history to this new repo (it will have a different first commit).

I can get the sha1 of the first commit using:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H @ %ai (%an)" | tail -1
```

How can I get the directory of the clone in the pre-receive hook?

Comment: fyi, Git should automatically prevent people from pushing from old history because the sha IDs won't match, making it a non-fast-forward push. They would have to force push in that case, which you could disable on the remote too...but maybe you don't want to disable force push completely, is that correct?

Comment: yes, i would like to keep the force option possible

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [pre-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) which reads each received ref.

If the *first* received head has no parent, that means someone is pushing the *all* history of the master branch, instead of a few commits.

```
git rev-list $new-ref
```

(It should return only itself, if `$new-ref` is a root commit, with no parent)

If that is the case, reject the commit (`exit 1`).

If not, don't block the push.